# plupload with ASP.NET MVC 4 getting Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'plupload' is undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, plupload

I'm working on an MVC 4 app to accept uploaded files from users. I am new to plupload and MVC 4 beta, so maybe there's something simple I'm missing.

I am using the following:

- ASP.NET MVC 4 (beta)
- jQuery 1.7.1
- jQuery UI 1.8.18
- plupload 1.5.2

I have the default folder structure with the exception of having an asset folder that contains the src folder for plupload named as plupload, i.e.:  "~/Assets/plupload/plupload.full.js" I did this to try to isolate the scripts from the normal scripts folder in an effort to isolate this error and prevent the bundler from grabbing these in alphabetical order.

On that note, I am aware of the bundling sequence issue when using the default bundle behavior and I think I have taken steps to control that. Originally, I created a custom bundle for just the plupload stuff but that served asynchronously which could have been a problem for my sequence enforcement. I then added the files to the default "~/Scripts/js" bundle. Unfortunately, the 'plupload' is undefined error is thrown by jQuery UI Mouse 1.8.18 still.

My Shared_Layout.cshtml contains this (Of course this is used for all pages, not just the upload page) I wasn't sure if it would be a problem or not. I also tried a _Layout page for just the upload page. :

```
...
<link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Content/themes/base/css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles.ResolveBundleUrl("~/Scripts/js")"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
    <header>
       ...
```

The Global.asax contains...

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Default method that fires when the application starts.
    /// </summary>
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        BundleTable.Bundles.RegisterTemplateBundles();

        Bundle b = BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor("~/Scripts/js");

        b.AddFile("~/Assets/plupload/plupload.full.js");
        b.AddFile("~/Assets/plupload/jquery.plupload.queue/jquery.plupload.queue.js");
        b.AddFile("~/Assets/plupload/jquery.ui.plupload/jquery.ui.plupload.js");
```

The actual upload page is:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Upload Files";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
// Convert divs to queue widgets when the DOM is ready
$(function () {
    $("#uploader").plupload({
        // General settings
        runtimes: 'gears,flash,silverlight,html5,html4',
        url: '/FileManager/Upload',
        // CLC >> No Limit
        // max_file_size: '10mb',
        chunk_size: '1mb',
        unique_names: true,

        // CLC >> Need original resolutions.
        // Resize images on clientside if we can
        // resize: { width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90 },

        // Specify what files to browse for
        filters: [
        { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
        { title: "Designer Files", extensions: "ai,indd" },
        { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
    ],

        // Flash settings
        flash_swf_url: '/Assets/plupload/plupload.flash.swf',

        // Silverlight settings
        silverlight_xap_url: '/Assets/plupload/plupload.silverlight.xap'
    });

    // Client side form validation
    $('form').submit(function (e) {
        var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');

        // Files in queue upload them first
        if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
            // When all files are uploaded submit form
            uploader.bind('StateChanged', function () {
                if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                    $('form')[0].submit();
                }
            });

            uploader.start();
        } else
            alert('You must at least upload one file.');

        return false;
    });
    });
</script>


<h2>Upload Files</h2>

<form action="Upload">
<div id="uploader">
    <p>Sorry, you browser doesn't have Flash, Silverlight, Gears, HTML5 or HTML4 support. Please try to upload using a different web browser or install one or more of these runtimes and try again:<br /><br />
    </p>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">Adobe Flash Player</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/">Microsoft Silverlight</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</form>
```

Using Fiddler2, I can see that the bundle is getting created and minified. Every page (including the home page) gets the error in the mouse function. Any ideas on what I can do to get this going?

Does anyone know of a COMPLETE MVC 4 sample using plupload? The product contains samples for Silverlight, php, etc. but there seems to have been some recent changes in the distribution (plupload.full.js vs. plupload.js) that shakes up the samples.

Comment: I have all but given up on the jQuery UI flavor. I switched to the plupload queue and I can at least get the runtime to show on the screen. Geez... I've never had such trouble with this kinda stuff.

Comment: You still having problems with this? jQuery is very very helpful. I hope you did not give up. If you still need help then let me know. Use @ and my nick to message me in this comment.

Comment: I found that the bundle was causing errors with the newest jquery/jquery-ui due to the minification they do.  probably someone just didn't want to use a semi-colon again, to save a char.  The only way I could fix it was to remove the bundle and put them all in their own individual script tags in the _layout.cshtml.